# Remove empty Dictionary entry

Tags: c#, dictionary, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to make a Price Range filter as you can [see live here](http://roldskov.sp34k.dk/produkter/cykler/mountain-bikes/).
It's made in Umbraco 7.

I would like to hide a price range IF there is NO products in the range.

My code looks like this:

```
    string selectedpriceRange = queryString.Get("priceRange");

<ul id="priceFilter" class="section sidebarList">
    <li @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedpriceRange) ? currentClass : "")>
        <a href="@CurrentPage.Url@queryStringBuilder("priceRange", "")">All prices</a>
    </li>

 @{  var priceRanges = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            priceRanges.Add(0, 4999);
            priceRanges.Add(5000, 9999);
            priceRanges.Add(10000, 14999);
            priceRanges.Add(15000, 24999);
            priceRanges.Add(25000, 34999);
            priceRanges.Add(35000, 44999);
            priceRanges.Add(45000, 54999);
            priceRanges.Add(55000, 95000);
        }
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> range in priceRanges)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@CurrentPage.Url@queryStringBuilder("priceRange", string.Format("{0}-{1}", range.Key, range.Value))">
                    @string.Format("{0} - {1}", range.Key, range.Value)
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

I would like to think it's possible to add a `.where` or `Count` in the `new Dictionary` to see IF there is anything in that price range, but I'm not sure.

Comment: A dictionary seems  weird choice of data structure. Do you plan to use the low end of a price range as a key to look up the value of the high end?

Comment: It could very well be an odd choice Petter, I did not write the code, a friend of mine did as I'm not strong in this. Would you recommend a different and better approach?

Comment: Any data structure that can store two values can represent the upper and lower bounds of price range. Thus a dictionary is possible, but really intended for a completely purpose. A list of custom class would be more natural. As your code stands, I don't see any products, and the question of whether a price range is empty makes no sense.

Comment: "really intended for a completely _different_ purpose"

Comment: Your code is wrong.  Your range.Value is the upper price range (not the value).   Your dictionary should be new Dictionary<KeyPairValue<int, int>, List<decimal>>();